# SharePoint 2010 - How can we get list template name from the list if the list is created from ListTemplate

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-listtemplate, list-template

We have created a few list templates in the sharepoint and created the lists with using List Templates. Here is the example,

**ListTemplates**

1. ListTemplate1
2. ListTemplate2
3. ListTemplate3

Lists created following way,

List1 is created using ListTemplate1 
List2 is created using ListTemplate2 
List3 is created using ListTemplate3

And later user created List4 using ListTemplate1,

Now we are trying to identify which list is created by which template. But we couldn't identify the listtemplate properly. It is always coming as ListTemplate1 in few site colelctions, ListTemplate2 is the few site collections

Can anyone help me to get the correct listtemplate name for list?

Below is the Powershell code I have used to get list template for particular list.

```
$sourceWebURL = "WebUrl"
$sourceListName = "listname"

$spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $sourceWebURL
$spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$sourceListName]
$spSourceList.TemplateFeatureId
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this approach, in my case it returned the correct list templates

```
    if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
        Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell";
    }

    $_URL = "URL";
    $SPWeb = Get-SPWeb $_URL;

    $SPList = $SPWeb.Lists["LIST_NAME"];
    $listTemplate = $SPWeb.ListTemplates | ? {$_.FeatureId -eq $SPList.TemplateFeatureId};
    $listTemplate.Name;
    $listTemplate.FeatureId;
```

let me know if it was of any help

*** UPDATE ***
here is a small script to get all templates from web

```
     if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
        Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell";
    }

    $_URL = "[URL]";
    $SPWeb = Get-SPWeb $_URL;

    foreach($templates in $SPWeb.ListTemplates){
        $templates.Name;
        $templates.FeatureId;
        $templates.InternalName;
        $templates.SchemaXml;
    }
```

What You could do is to check if maybe no property (check also other props, not only the ones I mention in the script, You can always just check $tempplate object to get all) is different for this 3 templates You have. Maybe FeatureId is the same but check also the featureId in SchemaXml, maybe there is different. If all properties are the same what You could do is to update the 'description' property for the first template with this featureId like 'temp1' and second with value 'temp2' and so on. After that You can check if template You get from the list has always the same description. Probably it will be the same, if Yes then my next approach would be to try to update the featureId but please be aware that it is rather not recommended approach and may produce some errors. Maybe a better idea would be to try to reproduce the error on some dev environment and try to fix it there with changing the featureId.

Also You can check the SPExport and SPImport on list to maybe try to export those list and import them on some dev environment and try to fix this problem there.

Comment: Hi @Adam,  I have tried the above script in the environment but it giving the wrong template name. Note: I have uploaded three templates(created out of the custom list) to site and all the list template feature id's are same. Due to this, I am getting the wrong template name. Let me know if you need further information

Comment: And the template name You are getting now is the custom list template or one of those three? Maybe it would be a better idea to get list templates collection from web and that way try to find the correct one

Comment: Hi @Adam, I am getting the list template name from one of three templates as it is matching feature id. And We have tried to the list templates from site and web(it internally returned the same list templates) and compare, but it is also giving wrong template name as feature id in list template id is same for all.

Comment: check my latest update... I hope it will be of any help

Comment: Hi @Adam, Thanks for reply. I see the featurexml comparison is looks good. But we spoke to microsoft and they have confirmed that, there is not way to identify list to template mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Sample script to get template name for your reference.

```
$sourceWebURL = "http://sp10/"
$sourceListName = "ListBasedonTemplate1"

$spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $sourceWebURL
$spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$sourceListName]
$spSourceList.TemplateFeatureId
$listTemplate=$spSourceWeb.Site.GetCustomListTemplates($spSourceWeb) | ? {$_.FeatureId -eq $spSourceList.TemplateFeatureId}
$listTemplate[0].Name
```

Comment: Hi @Lee_MSFT, I have tried the above script in the environment but it giving the wrong template name. **Note:** I have uploaded three templates(created out of the custom list) to site and all the list template feature id's are same. Due to this, I am getting the wrong template name. Let me know if you need further information